# UWP c# DataRequest.FailWithDisplayText deprecated

Tags: c#, uwp

VS 2015 Update 3 shows me recently DataRequest.FailWithDisplayText as deprecated. For more info, see MSDN. Unfortunately, I find nothing. What is the alternative to DataRequest.FailWithDisplayText?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no alternative to [DataRequest.FailWithDisplayText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datarequest.failwithdisplaytext.aspx) now. This issue seems related to the `DeprecatedAttribute` for this method which is added in Windows 10 10586+ SDK. You can find this by hit `F12` on `FailWithDisplayText` method.

```
[Deprecated("FailWithDisplayText is deprecated and might not work on all platforms. For more info, see MSDN.", DeprecationType.Deprecate, 131072, "Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract")]
public void FailWithDisplayText(System.String value);
```

I will report this issue using our internal channel and update here if there is any progress. For now, you can just ignore this message. `FailWithDisplayText` method should still be able to work now.

**Update:**

This issue has been fixed in Windows 10 Creators Update. With Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0), there should be no warning now.

Comment: @hellodear This issue should have been fixed in the latest **Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0)**. You can upgrade your system to Creators Update (Version 1703) and use the latest Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.1 (26403.03)) and set your project's Target version to **Windows 10 Creators Update (10.0; Build 15063)**. Then there should be no warning.